# Get x and y Movement Based On Angle, Sort Of

Tags: java, c#, math, game-maker

I know how to do this normally, assuming that up is 0 degrees

```
X += Speed * Math.Cos(angle);

Y += speed * Math.Sin(angle);
```

But I don't know how to do it if I assume that up is actually 270 degrees, and right is 0 degrees. (I am using Game Maker, and they decided to make right be 0 degrees instead of up)

How would I go about doing this? There may be a simple solution I am overlooking, but I am not the brightest when it comes to math.

Comment: You want to convert angle from one axes to another, don't you?

Comment: Can't you just `cos(270 + angle)`?

Comment: Is this Java or C#? Because in Java, the parameter to [`Math.sin()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin%28double%29) is in *radians*, not degrees.

Comment: @Andreas I know it is in radians, I am converting it from degrees to radians, that isn't the issue.

Comment: @gh0st 1. The "angle" is in radians, and even if I convert to degrees, add 270, and convert back, it doesn't work.

Comment: You should really remove the tag in which this is not being written in. If you're putting both java and c# you're going to get different answers.

Comment: "even if I [...] it doesn't work." - update your question with *that* code, something must be slightly wrong there. Offsetting the angle by -90 / 270 degrees is the correct solution.

Comment: Alternatively, simply swap Sin and Cos around

Comment: You realize that it's not a right handed coordinate system anymore.  If you cross the x-axis into the y-axis, the resulting z-axis points into the screen, not out.  I just want you to be aware.

Answer (score 0):

X += Speed * Math.Cos((angle  + 270)  % 360);

That's what I would do. Since you're rotating the graph 270 degree counterclockwise.

Comment: Shouldn't have to mod by 360. The domain of cosine isn't limited from 0-360.

Answer (score 0):

## Angle Adjustment

All you should have to do is adjust the angle. You measure North as `0 degrees` this program measures North as `270 degrees`. To fix this, simply subtract the `270` that they are off by. Something like this ought to suffice:

```
# angle is the programs offset version (North=270)
# corrected_angle is your fixed version (North=0)

corrected_angle = angle-270; # mod by 360 if you it to be non-negative

X += Speed * Math.Cos(corrected_angle);

Y += speed * Math.Sin(corrected_angle);
```

**[ Note:** If (1,0) and (0,1) aren't where you expect, then you will need to adjust more than just the angle. Also this assumes that the angle increases as you go clockwise in the program and that you want the angle to increase as you go clockwise. **]**

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact using GameMaker, then they have functions called lengthdir_x and lengthdir_y that do exactly what you are looking for (finding lengths in terms of a magnitude and angle in degrees).